# Why does boost::asio::io_service not compile with std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile simple test program with `std::thread`, `std::bind` and `boost::asio` using `g++` 4.9.1 (`-std=c++11`).

However, when creating new thread, it doesn't compile, when I use `std::bind`. On the other hand, when I switch to `boost::bind` everything is fine.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;

    t.reset(new std::thread(std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)));
    //t.reset(new std::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)));
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:12:80: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::asio::io_service*)’
    t.reset(new std::thread(std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)));
                                                                                            ^
test.cpp:12:80: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:79:0,
             from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1623:5: note: template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
 bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1623:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:80: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Func’
    t.reset(new std::thread(std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)));
                                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:79:0,
             from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1650:5: note: template<class _Result, class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bindres_helper<_Result, _Func, _BoundArgs>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
 bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1650:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:80: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Result’
    t.reset(new std::thread(std::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)));
                                                                            ^
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between C++11 std::bind and boost::bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/is-there-any-difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Was thinking the same but trying it out proved me wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message indicate that `std::bind()` cannot determine which [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) overload to use:

```cpp
std::size io_service::run();
std::size io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&);
```

For this particular case, Boost.Bind does not have an issue, but it does provide some troubleshooting for [binding an overloaded functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.troubleshooting.binding_an_overloaded_function).  It recommends either casting:

```cpp
std::bind(
  static_cast<std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run),
  &ioService);
```

Or using a temporary variable:

```cpp
std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*run)() = &boost::asio::io_service::run;
std::bind(run, &ioService);
```

---

The reason why the explicit casting is needed for `std::bind()` but not `boost::bind()` is due to implementation details.  If the arity of the call to `bind()` does not place constraints on the type of function being binded, then explicit casting will be required for overloaded functions.

For instance, consider the case where a variadic template is used:

```
template<class F, class... BoundArgs>
unspecified std::bind(F&& f, BoundArgs&&... bound_args);
```

When the best matching `std::bind()` overload is being selected, the arity of the call to `std::bind()` places no restrictions on `F`.  As `F` could be either of the following:

- `std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()`
- `std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)(boost::system::error_code&)`

the expression `&boost::asio::io_service::run()` is ambiguous.

On the other hand, Boost.Bind is implemented with overloaded functions wherein the arity of the call to `boost::bind()` places constraints on the arity of the function being binded.  Its interface [synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.interface.synopsys) lists the following noteworthy overloads:

```cpp
// 2 args: member-to-function (arity:0), instance
template <class R, class T, class A1>
unspecified bind(R (T::*f)(), A1 a1);

// 3 args: member-to-function (arity:1), instance, arg1
template <class R, class T, class B1, class A1, class A2>
unspecified bind(R (T::*f)(B1), A1 a1, A2 a2);
```

Note that when `boost::bind()` has:

- an arity of 2, the pointer-to-member function has an arity of 0
- an arity of 3, the pointer-to-member function has an arity of 1

Hence, when calling:

```cpp
boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)
```

The `boost::bind()` overloads that are potential matches have an arity of 2, so the pointer-to-member function must be a type of function with an arity of 0.  As only a single function in the set of `io_service::run()` overloads has an arity of 0, the call is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the error message `boost::asio::io_service::run` is overloaded or member template and `std::bind()` can't determine which overload or instantiation it is meant to use. You'll need to use something like this which deduces the appropriate type when taking the address, e.g.,

```
static_cast<std:size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()>(&boost::asio::io_service::run)
```

The key issue is that taking the address of `boost::asio::io_service::run` results in two choices for the member function but at the time the address is taken there isn't any way to determine which one to use. Only when the member function is used it is clear that the version taking no additional arguments is meant to be used. The address-of operator won't produce an overload set, however.

To deduce which overload is needed, `std::bind()` would need to provide an overload of itself which has the appropriate type as its first argument. However, it has no way to determine what that type should be, I think. I don't know how it actually works with `std::boost::bind()`! I *could* imagine that `boost::bind()` has special overloads for member functions with no argument and, possibly, one for `boost::error_code` but I don't really see how that would help.

It may be easier to use a lambda function, though:

```
std::thread t([&](){ ioService.run(); });
t.join(); // without a joining or detaching terminate() is called
```

Comment: As I said in other comment, I don't get why can't it resolve the corrent 'run' version. The argument list is different, so it is obvious. Casting and lamda works, but it is totally changing the problem. BTW, I didn't write join, becuse I only wanted to demonstrate problem.

Comment: The arity of the call to `boost::bind()` restricts the arity of the function type being bound.  In this particular case, the arity is enough to disambiguate the overloads.  See the Boost.Bind interface [synopsis](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Synopsis).

Answer (score 1):

the key to understanding this error is the `unresolved overloaded function type` part

this means the compiler couldnt figure out which overloaded version of `boost::asio::io_service::run` to use.

Looking up in [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) one see there are 2 versions, you want to use the `std::size_t run()` one. To communicate this to the compiler we need to `static_cast` the function pointer to explicit type of the overloaded variant, here `std:size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)()`

hence we write `static_cast<std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*)(void)>(&boost::asio::io_service::run)` in place of just `&boost::asio::io_service::run`

the full code looks like this then

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService;
std::unique_ptr<std::thread> t;

t.reset(new std::thread(std::bind(
    static_cast<std::size_t(boost::asio::io_service::*)(void)>(&boost::asio::io_service::run),
    &ioService
)));
```

Comment: Your casting works, but still I don't get it, because those 2 overloaded version have different argument list, so what's the problem for std::bind. Maybe that suggested "possible duplicate" will help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Bind supports smart pointers bound as the this argument for bound member functions.

This is a rather big (and awesome) difference between std::bind and boost::bind.

Boost Asio has always promoted patterns¹ that rely heavily on binding to `shared_pointer<T>` where `T` can be anything with "magically managed"  lifetime in the context of asynchronous IO, such as `connection`, `client`, `session`, `transfer` etc.

Of course c++11 lambdas can support the same directly (by capturing a shared pointer by copy).

---

¹ e.g.

- [boost asio deadline_timer async_wait(N seconds) twice within N seconds cause operation canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960268/boost-asio-deadline-timer-async-waitn-seconds-twice-within-n-seconds-cause-ope/25963523#25963523)
- [Proper cleanup with a suspended coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739647/proper-cleanup-with-a-suspended-coroutine/26740429#26740429)

Comment: Maybe I fail to see the point but what has the smart-pointer related functionality of `boost::bind` to do with its ability to somehow magically resolve overloads?

Comment: @bamboon Who says that it does? How many of these overloads do you see? And what is magic about the resolution, given that the library special cases (smart) pointers? Since it knows how to use them, it can bind the function call. The arity is fixed so there is no ambiguity. There's really *nothing* that does *not* have to with the smart-pointer related functionality of boost::bind AFAICT

Comment: I see [two](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) overloads with different arity.

Comment: Mmm. I guess you're right.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7763d779977cec18 vs. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5855b43f8f08fbd6 tells me there's a difference I wasn't previously aware of. TIL